# Inequality about $p$-norm of fourier like coefficient.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis

I want to show that if $\{c_{i}\}_{i=1}^{N}$ is a set of complex numbers, then $$ \int_{0}^{1} |\sum_{j=1}^{N}c_{j}\exp(2\pi i j t)|^{p} dt \leq \sum_{j=1}^{N}|c_{j}|^{p} \textrm{ when } 1\leq p \leq 2$$
and
$$ \int_{0}^{1} |\sum_{j=1}^{N}c_{i}\exp(2\pi i j t)|^{p} dt \geq \sum_{j=1}^{N}|c_{j}|^{p} \textrm{ when } 2\leq p <\infty$$

I tried to apply the triangle inequality, $|a+b|^{p} \leq 2^{p}(|a|^{p}+|b|^{p}),$ Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma, however, it fails. Because of $\exp(2\pi i n t)$ term, I think it is related to Fourier Analysis, however, I don't know much about that.

Could you give me a hint for approach this problem?

Comment: Why the cases $1\leq p\leq 2$ and $2\leq p<\infty$ amount to the same upper bound? Then your question is actually addressing one inequality?

Comment: @user284331 Thank you for letting me know. I edited it.

Comment: The second inequality is wrong, at least in the case that $p = 2$. The left hand side is (essentially) $\sum_{i = 1}^N |c_i|^2$ which does not dominate the right hand side. Actually, this means both inequalities are wrong. Perhaps you want $|c_i|^p$ or some variant on the right.

Comment: @user296602 Um, Since second inequality contains equality, so I think it's okay. If you don't mind, could you let me know why the left hand side is equal to right hand side when $p=2$?

Comment: @user296602 Oh I see. I forgot to add $p$-th power. Thanks!

Comment: In $p = 2$, use Plancherel. For other $p$, try to see what happens with $p = 1$ and interpolate, perhaps. Duality could handle the other case.

Comment: @user296602 Thank you! I will try your approach!